# Solve ODE with exactness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve the following ODE with exactness.

$$ e^{2x}(2\cos(y)-\sin(y)y')=0 \;, y(0)=0 $$

working through this question I got the answer $e^{2x}\cos(y)=0$ which doesn't seem correct. Assistance in finding the actual answer would be gratefully appreciated thank you

Comment: What happened to the equal sign in the first equation?

Comment: oh sorry i have edited the question now

Comment: $e^{2x}(2cos(y)-sin(y)y')$ isn't an equation.  There's no equal sign.  What is equal to what?

Comment: But $e^{2x}$ is never $0$.  You can divide both sides by $e^{2x}$ and then it's just an indefinite integral, isn't it?

Comment: Is your question stated correctly? The $e^{2x}$ factor seems unnecessary.

Comment: As stated the equation is fully separable

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes the question is stated correctly

Comment: @YuriyS it maybe be separable but I have to use exactness

Comment: @saulspatz true I can divide out the $e^{2x}$ i will attempt the question using this method

Comment: It's not exact without the exponential. So you shouldn't factor that out if you have to use exactness

Comment: @YuriyS oh yh that is true i will keep the exponential in that case

Comment: Going from my own answer it seems like your solution had been correct, only you forgot to add a constant on the right hand side.

Answer (score 3):

Just integrate ...since $(e^{2x}\ne 0)$

$$e^{2x}(2\cos(y)-\sin(y)y')=0 \;, y(0)=0$$
$$2\cos(y)-\sin(y)y'=0$$
$$\int \frac{\sin(y)} {\cos(y)}dy=2x+K$$
$$\ln|\cos(y)|=-2x+K$$
$$y(0)=0 \to K=0$$
$$x=-\frac {\ln|\cos(y)|} 2$$

---

Edit 
For exactness
$$e^{2x}2\cos(y)dx-e^{2x}\sin(y)dy=0$$
$$df=P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy$$
$$\partial_yP=\partial_ye^{2x}2\cos(y)=-2e^{2x}\sin(y)$$
$$\partial_xQ=-\partial_xe^{2x}\sin(y)=-2e^{2x}\sin(y)$$
The differential is exact, after integration we get
$$e^{2x}\cos(y)=K$$
using the cauchy condition:
 $$y(0)=0 \to K=1 \to e^{2x}\cos(y)=1$$
it's the same answer as in the first part of my answer
$$e^{2x}\cos(y)=1 \to \ln{(e^{2x}\cos(y))}=0 \to \ln|\cos(y)|=-2x$$

Comment: Good one! Took me too long to type from mobile

Comment: yw @YuriyS latex on mobile is really hard lol

Comment: The questions asks to solve using exactness though

Answer (score 3):

As the OP stated the equation to be correct, we can get rid of the exponential and solve:

$$2\cos(y)-\sin(y)y'=0$$

$$2\cos(y)dx=\sin(y)dy$$

$$2x=\int \tan(y)dy =\int \frac{ \sin y }{ \cos y} dy =- \int \frac{d \cos y }{ \cos y} =-\ln \cos y + C$$

---

Edit:

Since the OP actually needs to use the exact equation methods, let's get the exponential back:

$$2e^{2x}\cos(y)dx-e^{2x}\sin(y)dy=0$$

Checking for exactness:

$$\partial_y \left(2e^{2x}\cos(y) \right)=-2e^{2x}\sin(y)$$

$$\partial_x \left(-e^{2x}\sin(y) \right)=-2e^{2x}\sin(y)$$

The equation is exact.

The implicit solution will be:

$$\int 2e^{2x}\cos(y) dx=e^{2x} \cos y =C_1$$

Which is equivalent to the solution obtained by separation of variables (the constants are different).